# How to remove non-ascii characters from XML data

Tags: c#, regex, xml, non-ascii-characters

I have some XML data that is in the following format. My application is supposed to read this using a XMLReader and do some processing to it . However, for that to happen, I need to remove or replace the first portion of each line, specifically the `<���`.

```
<���<XML>....data....</XML>
<���<XML>....data....</XML
<���<XML>....data....</XML>    
and so on...
```

I tried the following after looking at some posts in SO but no success so far. Any help will be appreciated!

```
private static Regex _invalidXMLChars = new Regex(
@"(?<![\uD800-\uDBFF])[\uDC00-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F-\x9F\uFEFF\uFFFE\uFFFF]",
RegexOptions.Compiled);

        static string ReplaceHexadecimalSymbols(string txt)
        {
            return _invalidXMLChars.Replace(txt, string.Empty);
        }
```

Note: I took my XML data which is in .txt format and tried calling the function on each line but it did not work.. the characters were still there after calling the function.

Comment: What do you get when you read the file with UTF8 encoding? Seems like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem)

Comment: The same thing, the characters are still there   @EZI

Comment: If you read the file's bytes, what bytes do you see at the position of these � characters?

Comment: Try to convert each char to ushort and check if the range is from 32 - 126 (last displayable character) and if it's below 32 make sure it's a character that can be displayed like tab.

Comment: [Have a look at this solution](http://ideone.com/NiCpgi), does it work for you?

Comment: Why do you call it XML data when it isn't?

Answer (score 1):

I would investigate as to why these characters are there in the first place. It looks like some encoding problem somewhere between the original XMLs and your file.

Anyway, when you read a line, just drop all the characters before the `<XML>`.

Comment: So some 'xml's are broken by newlines? You should definitely figure out what caused this.